# Interoperability by using Spring and Hessian ? Is it possible?

Tags: java, spring, interop, hessian

Spring in Action book says:

> Hessian, like RMI, uses binary messages to communicate between client and service. However, unlike other binary remoting technologies (such as RMI), the binary message IS PORTABLE to languages other than Java, including PHP, Python, C++, and C#. (316)

Can you give me some advice how can i get it ? That is, by using PHP, for instance, i can read a Hessian messsage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the list of [Hessian implementations](http://hessian.caucho.com/#Hessian%20Implementations/Download): [PHP Implementation of Hessian](http://hessianphp.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, see [17.3. Using Hessian or Burlap to remotely call services via HTTP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/remoting.html#remoting-caucho-protocols) in the Spring reference.